# Reactjs: Why child components aren't re-rendering on data change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React.js suppose to re-render all sub components (children) when state of root component changes?

Please have a look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/F8H7p/8/

In the above example, Only `Search` sub-component re-renders when the state of `Dashboard` component changes. But other sub-components - Section, Chart & Widget do not re-render.

This is how my renderComponent looks:

```
React.renderComponent(Dashboard({title: "D", children: [Section({title: "S", children: [Widget({title: "W"}), Chart()]})]}), document.body);
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F8H7p/21/ switching to jsx in React.renderComponent seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you update Dashboard, React re-renders each component created by the Dashboard render method. In this case, you're passing in components via `this.props.children` and so it's expected that they don't depend on Dashboard's state and so they aren't re-rendered.

If this isn't the case for your app, you probably want to create a higher-level Page component that handles this state and renders the Dashboard component along with its children. With that structure, your renderComponent call would just be something like:

```
React.renderComponent(Page(), document.body);
```